# How to expose Homebrew to PHP

Tags: php, macos, nginx, homebrew

I need to be able to run programs installed via brew within PHP.
I can run said programs if I specify the full path to the binary.

The NGINX and PHP services are both running under my own user `alexandra`, yet PHP doesn't load my shell profile, which has the `PATH` variable set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a middleware class that simply loads my local zsh profile.

```php
if (PHP_OS === 'Darwin') {
    $command = 'source ~/.zprofile;' . $command;
```